# "Partial" Total Internal Reflection

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, interference, geometric-optics

Can partial TIR happen?
Consider the [image present in this link](http://www.physics-assignment.com/interference-in-thin-films)

Here, at point D, TIR happens, but also there is transmission.

Is "total" internal reflection a misnomer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total internal reflection should not be confused with reflection! (Although they are quite the same).

Total internal reflection occurs when the incident light strikes the interface at an angle *greater* than the critical angle. And the ray should travel from a denser medium to a rarer medium. The light gets *totally* reflected (All of it is reflected back).

Reflection, on the other hand, is just like light bouncing off a mirror. There is no *minimum* or *maximum* angle that is required. The light, in this case, is not guaranteed to be *totally* reflected. Some of it could simply pass through the interface and be *refracted*.

At point D, the light is being partially refracted and partially *reflected*.

Comment: Oh, absolutely right. I thought there cannot be any simple reflection when there is no phase change after the reflection.